# Error in Programmatically creating Taxonomy in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I'm getting the below error while building taxonomy voccabulary and terms using the following code

> FieldException: Attempt to create an instance of a field field_my_custom_vocab002 that doesn't exist or is currently inactive. in field_create_instance() (line 476 of C:\wamp\www\pur_theme\modules\field\field.crud.inc).

I checked the voccabulary and it is created, the problem is only with term creation

## code

```
<?php

$new_vocab = (object) array(
    'name' => 'My custom vocabulary002',
    'description' => 'Test',
    'machine_name' => 'my_custom_vocab002',
  );
taxonomy_vocabulary_save($new_vocab);

$vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('my_custom_vocab002');

$term1 = (object) array(
   'name' => 'Term 1',
    'description' => 'This is term 1',
   'vid' => $vocab->vid,
);

taxonomy_term_save($term1);
```

What/where did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you try to create a term with more fields than the 2 basical ones (name and vid). You have a "description" field in addition.

Try this code instead:

```
$term = new stdClass();
$term->name = 'Term 1';
$term->vid = $vocab->vid; 
$term->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'This is term 1'; 
taxonomy_term_save($term);
```

Source: http://www.lightrains.com/blog/programmatically-create-taxonomy-term-drupal

Comment: `$term->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` is not the case for taxonomy_term description field. It should be `$term->description`, because description column exists inside taxonomy_term_data db table.

Comment: `$term->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'This is term 1'; 
` this is used for new field.

Answer (score 0):

I found the only solution to this was to create the field it's looking for before creating the vocabulary. Personally I did this with a custom function:

```
function MY_MODULE_create_new_taxonomy($taxonomy_name, $taxonomy_machine_name, $taxonomy_description){

  //Add field you know is going to cause trouble
  $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_'.$taxonomy_machine_name,
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Label'
  );

  field_create_field($field);

  //create the vocab
  $new_vocabulary = new stdClass();
  $new_vocabulary->name = $taxonomy_name;
  $new_vocabulary->machine_name = $taxonomy_machine_name;
  $new_vocabulary->description = t($taxonomy_description);
  $new_vocabulary->module = 'taxonomy';

  taxonomy_vocabulary_save($new_vocabulary);

}
```